# Registration returns "401 unauthorized" but request is confirmed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-routing

I wrote a registration module, the first step is that users register their account as requests, and administrator will confirm requests as next step. However, I don't know why my registering request part doesn't work, the status code returns 401 unauthorised, but confirming request works well, even  though they are in a same router. Here is my code.

In sign up controller:

```
$scope.signUp = function(){
    var req = {
        username:       $scope.username, 
        password:       $scope.password, 
        email:          $scope.email,
        firstName:      $scope.user.firstName,
        lastName:       $scope.user.lastName,
        contactNumber:  $scope.user.contactNumber,
        companyName:    $scope.user.companyName
    };

    $http.post('/register/request', req)
    .success(function(response){
        if(response === 'success'){
            tagInfoInstace = $uibModal.open({
                animation: true, 
                templateUrl: '../templates/modal_register_tag.html', 
                windowClass: 'modal-tag',
                resolve: {
                    data: function() {
                        return $scope.data;
                    }
                },
                size: 'sm'
            });

            $timeout(function() {
                $state.go('login');
            }, 2000);
        }
        else if(response.startsWith('failed')){
            console.log(response);
        }
        else if(response.startsWith('exist')){
            response.endsWith('user') ? $scope.usernameExisted = true : $scope.emailExisted = true;
        }
    })
    .error(function(response){
        console.log('post error: ' + response);
    });     
}
```

In my administration controller:

```
$scope.confirmTags = function() {
    var data = {};
    var i = 0;
    for(index in $scope.request_checked){
        if($scope.request_checked[index]){
            data[i] = $scope.requests[index];
            i++;
        }
    }

    $http.post('/register/user', data)
    .success(function(response){
        $scope.nonRequestChecked = true;
        $window.location.reload();
    })
    .error(function(response){
        console.log('register error: ' + response);
    });
}
```

and this is the router:

```
router.post('/register/:type', function(req, res, next){
if(req.params.type === 'request'){
    var request_user = new Request({
        username:       req.body.username,
        password:       req.body.password,
        email:          req.body.email,
        firstName:      req.body.firstName,
        lastName:       req.body.lastName,
        contactNumber:  req.body.contactNumber,
        companyName:    req.body.companyName
    });

    request_user.save(function(err) {
        if(err)
            res.send('failed: save error: ' + err);
        else
            res.send('success');
    });
}
else if(req.params.type === 'user'){
    var exception = {};
    for(index in req.body){
        var user = new User({
            username:       req.body[index].username,
            password:       req.body[index].password,
            email:          req.body[index].email,
            firstName:      req.body[index].firstName,
            lastName:       req.body[index].lastName,
            contactNumber:  req.body[index].contactNumber,
            companyName:    req.body[index].companyName
        });

        user.save(function(err) {
            if(err)
                exception[index] = 'failed: save error ' + index + ': ' + err;
        });

        Request.find().remove({username: req.body[index].username}).exec(function(err, feedback){
            if(err)
                exception[index*2] = 'delete error: ' + index + ': ' + err;
        });
    }
    res.send(exception);
}
```

});

Comment: What does `console.dir(req.body)` show, is it filled in appropriately or is it empty? Also, you're calling `res.send(exception)` before (all of) your async callbacks are complete which means `/register/user` will always send back an empty object.

Comment: the router rejected the post with error code 401 unauthorised, and thanks for figuring out the issue of async callbacks

Comment: Sounds like maybe there is an authentication middleware passing execution (e.g. via `next()`) to the route handler after already responding with 401?

Comment: Ohhh, you are right, I forgot that I had an access control middleware at the beginning. Fixed, thanks!